# Managing a table with multiple sublists

Tags: r, list, data-manipulation, tibble

I am doing some data exploration and iterated an ANOVA through a large number of variables (~ 300) and then did a pairwise comparison on the significant findings. I know from a statistical point of view this is frowned upon (I am using Bonferroni to at least minimize errors somewhat) and there are better ways to analyze data, but this is more of an exploratory analysis to see what general differences exist between 4 groups.

After I run the pairwise test the output becomes a table that looks like the following (only 4 variables shown for readability)

```
List of 163
 $ Var1      :List of 3
  ..$ comp  : num [1:6, 1:6] 1 1 1 2 2 3 2 3 4 3 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "Group" "Group" "psihat" "ci.lower" ...
  ..$ fnames: chr [1:4] "1" "3" "2" "4"
  ..$ call  : language mcppb20(formula = .x ~ lasi_data_grouped$Group)
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "mcp1"
 $ Var2     :List of 3
  ..$ comp  : num [1:6, 1:6] 1 1 1 2 2 3 2 3 4 3 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "Group" "Group" "psihat" "ci.lower" ...
  ..$ fnames: chr [1:4] "1" "3" "2" "4"
  ..$ call  : language mcppb20(formula = .x ~ lasi_data_grouped$Group)
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "mcp1"
 $ Var3   :List of 3
  ..$ comp  : num [1:6, 1:6] 1 1 1 2 2 3 2 3 4 3 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "Group" "Group" "psihat" "ci.lower" ...
  ..$ fnames: chr [1:4] "1" "3" "4" "2"
  ..$ call  : language mcppb20(formula = .x ~ lasi_data_grouped$Group)
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "mcp1"
 $ Var4 :List of 3
  ..$ comp  : num [1:6, 1:6] 1 1 1 2 2 3 2 3 4 3 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "Group" "Group" "psihat" "ci.lower" ...
  ..$ fnames: chr [1:4] "1" "3" "2" "4"
  ..$ call  : language mcppb20(formula = .x ~ lasi_data_grouped$Group)
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "mcp1"
```

Most of the useful information is present in the $ comp table. I can pull this out with the following code

```
results <- analysis %>%
  map_df(pluck, "comp")
```

This then looks like

```
$ Var1      : num [1:6, 1:6] 1 1 1 2 2 3 2 3 4 3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "Group" "Group" "psihat" "ci.lower" ...
 $ Var2     : num [1:6, 1:6] 1 1 1 2 2 3 2 3 4 3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "Group" "Group" "psihat" "ci.lower" ...
 $ Var3   : num [1:6, 1:6] 1 1 1 2 2 3 2 3 4 3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "Group" "Group" "psihat" "ci.lower" ...
 $ Var4 : num [1:6, 1:6] 1 1 1 2 2 3 2 3 4 3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "Group" "Group" "psihat" "ci.lower" ...
```

This is where I get stuck as I have tried to unnest these variables, tried pivot_longer, tried hoist without the ability to change this table and its variables.

It seems as each column in the table is type double and contains a table so doing further analysis or cleaning (using dplyr or ggplot) doesn't seem to work and functions (such as ends_with) don't work the names. Unfortunately I can't share the raw data to make this reproducible, but any guidance or tips would be much appreciated as I am a little stuck.

Please let me know if any other information is required!